# Payments Api Doesn't Return Link in Headers via C#

Tags: square-connect

I'm calling the Square Connect payments API using C#. The documentation says I should get a header key of "link" if results are paged. However, I only ever get 100 results in the response and there isn't a header key of "link".  Here's my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", "<Token>"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var paymentUrl = string.Format("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments?begin_time={0:yyyy-MM-dd}T00:00:00Z&end_time={1:yyyy-MM-dd}T00:00:00Z", startDate.AddDays(-25).Date, startDate.Date);

var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(paymentUrl);
```

Comment: Is account associated with <Token> a business or a location?

Comment: It's a business account.

Comment: After investigating this, I believe that there is a bug in pagination when using the combined payments endpoint for a business account (which merges the payments from all locations together). I've reported this to the API team. As a workaround, you can call the payments endpoint for each location, which should paginate correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Tony.  Using the individual location endpoints solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the `location_id` urls to retrieve your payment history with the v1 APIs. Alternatively you can use the [v2 Transaction APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-transactions) to more effectively retrieve your payment info.